# How do I return array of keys that have only empty values in the objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering

I am learning arrays/objects in ES5, now I have code like this that returns object of filtered non empty keys/values:

```js
var object = [{"notEmptyValue":"1","emptyValue1":"","notEmptyValue2":"1","emptyValue2":""}];

function removeEmpty(data) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    (data[key] && typeof data[key] === 'object') && removeEmpty(data[key]) ||
    (data[key] === '' || data[key] === null) && delete data[key] 
  });
  return JSON.stringify(data);
}

//returns [{"notEmptyValue":"1","notEmptyValue2":"1"}]
//but I would like [{"emptyValue1":"","emptyValue2":""}]
//OR the best ['emptyValue1', 'emptyValue2']
```

However, I need the opposite, where I need to return the ones that are empty. In the best case only the array of keys that are empty (see in the code snippet). How do I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of `Object.keys`, you use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then filter out anything that has a non-empty-string value. (or if you don't care about the keys, `Object.values()`)

Comment: Why is your object in between [... ] ?

Comment: @BülentAkgül because I was trying to display it form server to client and it was pure object, but it was giving me [object Object] so when I did the result to JSON.stringify[data] it put the object inside of an array so I could see it. Not sure if I am explaining it right, I am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` to get the object keys, and `filter` to leave only empty keys.

UPDATE: to do it over an array of objects, I used `map` and return from each object it's empty keys.

```js
let objects = [{
    "notEmptyValue": "1",
    "emptyValue1": "",
    "notEmptyValue2": "1",
    "emptyValue2": ""
  },
  {
    "notEmptyValue": "1",
    "emptyValue3": "",
    "notEmptyValue2": "1",
    "emptyValue4": ""
  }
];


let emptyKeys = objects.map(object => Object.keys(object).filter(key => object[key] === ''));;
console.log(emptyKeys);
```

Comment: This looks good to me and I get it however how do I do it in ES5? My browser/platform does not support '=>' type of functions :/

Comment: I got it figured out!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: One more question, what if I have something like {
  "notEmptyValue": "1",
  "emptyValue1": "",
  "notEmptyValue2": "1",
  "emptyValue2": ""
}, {
  "notEmptyValue": "1",
  "emptyValue1": "",
  "notEmptyValue2": "1",
  "emptyValue2": "2"
}; It crashed when I tried this

Comment: @JohnLong it's an array of objects? Use `forEach` on the array

Comment: yeah it is, Is there a way that you can edit the snippet? I keep getting empty array back :/

Comment: yes that's good, I was using the forEach because I wanted to get one array not two. But I would want too much probably :D